# Full and final settlement

Tags: settlement

Say you have signed the full and final settlement agreement between the claimant and the defendant for a fixed settlement fee in front of your presiding officer in a civil court.

What happens after the defendant pays the settlement fee to the claimant, and after the claimant receives the payment the claimant want to withdraw the settlement or make the settlement void?

Comment: What happens if you smash a plate and then decide you want to eat dinner off it?

Comment: U bleed i suppose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the defendant has fully complied with his obligations per the settlement, the claimant no longer has the option of withdrawing from, or voiding, the agreement.

The settlement is binding also for the claimant, and it cannot be voided unless the defendant agrees to its rescission.

Comment: I first read "settlement, withdrawal from, or voiding" as a list with an Oxford comma.  I have reworded to avoid that confusion.  The other alternative I considered was to put the parenthetical "or voiding" inside parens rather than commas.  Feel free to roll back my change if you don't like it.

Comment: Thank you a much better reply and understanding gained compared to unhelpful comments on the question. I appreciate it.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis Thank you kindly. And also I fail to grasp the ... sarcasm? ... poor attempt of analogy? ... other? ... of asking you about [smashing a plate](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/47536/full-and-final-settlement/47541?noredirect=1#comment92168_47536).